# What can I do to get my deserved badge on a closed question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, closed-questions

I have [a question that has been closed due to being too narrow, or too specific](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139986/what-is-causing-arithmetic-overflow-in-the-query-below).

I believe many people will benefit from that question when having to deal with arithmetic overflow in SQL Server, and it may or may not be considered too specific.

This question now has reached 2.5K views and instead of getting a badge I am getting lots of messages like this one:

[image]

What do I do to get this badge and stop this flow of messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've voted to re-open your question since it is likely to help future visitors to the site.

Comment: you have been doing a good work as a moderator of our DBA site and you have been very active too. I wish this does not become too much an engagement on top of your personal life, including other things, hobbies and people who also need your time and attention.

Comment: thanks, Marcello - although I'm not technically a moderator.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

This was a network-wide bug that affected multiple badges; the code *tried* to award them, and did everything (including notification) *except* actually award the badge. It was fixed within a short time, allowing the badge to be awarded, which meant it *finally stopped trying to do it*. Sorry, this was my fault - apologies for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>*From comments:*</sub>

[Andriy M:](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m) I think you've already done what little you could do: this looks very much like a bug and you've reported it.

[ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9): You did get the badge, about 50 minutes after posting this question (a few minutes after midday, at 12:06).

[marcello miorelli](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22336/marcello-miorelli) (OP): The flow of messages has stopped. I am not sure exactly when but it looks like it stopped as soon as I got the badge.